# Quote column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table containing 2 "uncommon" columns - `order` and `like`.

The table are replicated on two databases - `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`.

And i need same app to connect to both databases and use same query on both:

```
PageModel.where("`like` >= ?", params[:liked])
```

This will work in `MySQL` only.

How to make `ActiveRecord` to quote the column name?

Something like:

```
PageModel.where("%s >= ?" % quote_column_name(:like), params[:liked])
```

I found a method that is useless for now - it just returns the column name without quote it.

http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting:quote_column_name

Perhaps it is just a placeholder and there are another method that does this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This depends from from one database adapter to the other. So basically, each adapter overrides this method with their own definition.

You're interested in:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_column_name "my_column"
```