# How do I weave around string interpolation for activerecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to remove the string interpolation from the following query ( which works, I just rather not string interpolate into an activerecord query.)

==EDITED==

```
scope :working_on, -> (day) { joins(:schedule).where("schedules.#{day} = ?", true ).references(:schedule)}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're dynamically setting the column in the WHERE? What is the value of `day`? Is it one a limited set of possible values? If so, it is sufficient to check its value against an array of acceptable possibilities, making it less heinous to interpolate into the query.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900856/quote-column-name for appropriately quoting it after it has been validated

Comment: since this is only an equality query, you can do `where(schedules: { day => true })`